# Converting QS query string to Elastic cloud query

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, query-string

Is there any way we can convert query string using [qs npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) to elastic cloud query string ? which support all kind of nested query params, greater than, less than, values between ranges all kind of queries ?

any npm module, git hub code or code snippet which does this ?
Example : for my api I am supporting all kind of query params supported by qs npm module, where as my search api is fetching from elastic cloud.

so in case I get query as

```
?title=Resurgence&causes=General&location.city=Mysuru&latitude=12.9803047&longitude=77.62949349999997&distance=50000&pageNumber=0&pageSize=10& organisation._id=5c36dd152edb5028fd7655a4
```

then the query string will be converted into json object by qs npm module and it gives a json object as follows

```
{"title":"Resurgence","causes":"General","location.city":"Mysuru","latitude":"12.9803047","longitude":"77.62949349999997","distance":"50000","pageNumber":"0","pageSize":"10","organisation._id":"5c36dd152edb5028fd7655a4"}
```

Where as while searching in elastic search I suppose to convert the same into elastic search query object as follows. 
So I was just looking for a npm module which will convert query string json of qs module into elastic cloud query body?

```
{
  "index": "researchArticles",
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "status": "PUBLISHED"
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "title": {
                "query": "Resurgence",
                "operator": "or",
                "prefix_length": 1
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "causes": {
                "query": "General",
                "operator": "or",
                "prefix_length": 1
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "location.city": {
                "query": "Bengaluru",
                "operator": "or",
                "prefix_length": 1
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "pageNumber": {
                "query": "0",
                "operator": "or",
                "prefix_length": 1
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "pageSize": {
                "query": "10",
                "operator": "or",
                "prefix_length": 1
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "organisation._id": {
                "query": "5c36dd152edb5028fd7655a4",
                "operator": "or",
                "prefix_length": 1
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "should": {
          "range": {
            "startDate": {
              "gte": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "50000",
            "location.geoSpatial": {
              "lat": "12.9803047",
              "lon": "77.62949349999997"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sort": [
      {
        "_geo_distance": {
          "location.geoSpatial": "12.9803047,77.62949349999997",
          "order": "asc",
          "unit": "m"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what you're after?

Comment: @Val updated the question